# What's this port?

Tags: malware, ports

Listing all the ports currently in use on my mac running `$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP`, I see six entries starting with a weird-looking string of `"2BUA8C4S2"`.

A web search for that string yields some results, but no explanation of what it is. All my other ports have innocuous-looking identifiers such as `"homed"` and `"Google"`.

I get suspicious and worry about malware when I see things I don't recognize. What is `"2BUA8C4S2"` and how can I find out for myself?

Comment: Warning: not a mac user. I found [this](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=33046619) and [this](https://www.mfisp.com/html/help/network/20160525/1219.html), but no explanation. Is it using TCP ports 6258 and 6263 on your mac as well? Have you tried doing a packet capture?

Comment: Not sure if I should disclose the ports. I have not tried a packet capture. How would I go about that? Is it like the author of the mfisp.com post did it?

Comment: Yeah, WireShark is what I would use. There are a lot of guides to using WireShark if you're unfamiliar. You would be filtering with something like `tcp.port == ####` where #### is the port number. I will note that WireShark may or may not give you anything useful.

Comment: This is not so much a security question than a troubleshooting question.

Answer (score 1):

On examining closer, you will see that it listens to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1). It is used  for the 1Password extension to talk to the 1Password Agent.

It should listen to loopback only, like my cupsd does:

but it may accept connections from your own machine. Note that `::1` is the IPv6 loopback address.

How to determine if it is from your own machine:

- with `ifconfig -a` or `ip address`, you can see the IP adresses of your own machine
- At the end of the line of your `lsof`, there is a descriptions of the connection, for example:

```
TCP 192.168.178.123:33188->192.168.178.56:22 (ESTABLISHED)
```

This means:

- TCP stream
- source IP address 192.168.178.123
- Source port 33188
- destination IP 192.168.178.56
- destination port 22 (ssh)

So, a connection from the outside is a from-ip address that is not on your system connecting to a destination address that is on your system.

All should be encrypted (even if it is over loopback), so I doubt that wireshark will show anything usefull.

Comment: Two of the seven entries point to 127.0.0.1, but there are others as well. Two of them point at *:<some port>, one of them points from my ip to some other IP's SSL port and says "(ESTABLISHED)", and two point from [::1]<two distinct ports>. The ones that don't say (ESTABLISHED) all say (LISTEN). Any of that worry you?

Comment: Anything coming from outside your own system to this would certainly require some investigation. If it's from the outside IP address of your system, that should be OK. I've never seen access from other systems to 1Passwodagent.

Comment: How do I know if something is "coming from outside [my] own system"?